# Google Drive title contains query not working as expected

Tags: google-drive-api

Working with the search in the google drive api, I've noticed something that seems a little odd. For example, if I have a file named 'purple-people-eater.jpg' and I search with the query `title contains 'purple'` then it will return the file like it should. However, if I search with the query `title contains 'people'` then I get no results. If I rename the file to 'purple people eater.jpg' and run either of the above queries, then both will return the same file.

Here are the urls that return the search results.

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?access_token=my_access_token&q=title%20contains%20%27purple%27`

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?access_token=my_access_token&q=title%20contains%20%27people%27`

My question is, is this expected behavior? If so, is there a way to get around it (other than doing all the searching manually) and if not, then is something wrong in my `q` parameter, or could it be something else?

Comment: And thus we discover that Google cannot find that which was eaten.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the query from what I can tell. Think it is more of  bug or restriction in how titles are indexed.

Comment: @SteveBazyl, this isn't just happening with titles. I just uploaded a text file to my google drive with the contents 'this is a test'. Searching for 'this' returns my file, searching for 'thi' also returns my file, but searching for 'his' does not. Is there somewhere I can open a ticket for this issue?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15289018/drive-fileslist-query-returns-no-results-when-searching-for-a-number-in-a-title

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issue with Google Drive API Call when searching for a File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15777577/issue-with-google-drive-api-call-when-searching-for-a-file)