# Drive Files:List query returns no results when searching for a number in a title

Tags: google-drive-api

File query returns no result when searching for a number in a title. For example, if file title is "File.123", then search query "title contains 'File'" is successful, but query "title contains '123'" is not.

The problem can be easily reproduced in API explorer.

Also. the IndexableText field is no longer searchable, i.e. queries return no results when searching for values in that field.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My mistake. It seems that search is searching for whole words, and not for character sequences. So, 123 would never be found. If file name was "File 123" then the search would have results.