# Issue with Google Drive API Call when searching for a File

Tags: google-drive-api

If you create a file in your Drive named "HelloWorld" and you then make the following API Call, https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=title+contains+'World' 
the file does not come up in the results.

1. It works properly on ?fullText+contains+'World'
2. It also works on ?title+contains+'HelloW'

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behavior. `"title contains <substring>"` queries are not supported. This is  also true for the search functionality on the Google Drive front-end.

Comment: The expected behavior is not unexpected and bad for developer experience though. I'll be following up  with the issue in the long term to see what we can do.

Comment: Thanks, please convey to the team that on the Drive Front-end, it does support ^<substring> (i.e. "begins-with"...you can search for Hello)  And for some reason, as I noted above, when you search using the FullText attribute, it works for any substring (which is documented the same way as title: "contains").  So at the very least, should be some soft of consistency.